# TYPO3 and jh_captcha in own extension

Tags: validation, typo3, recaptcha, typo3-extensions

I have tried to implement jh_captcha into my own extension.

I have followed this documentation: https://docs.typo3.org/p/haffner/jh_captcha/4.0/en-us/Developer/Index.html#add-the-captcha-to-your-domain-model

But I keep getting this error: Validation failed while trying to call ... Controller->showAction().

If I remove @validate NotEmpty, it works, but recaptcha is obviously not validated.

I have googled and found others with same problem, but none of the solutions works, beside removing the notEmpty-line.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The `NotEmpty` is not required and the value is validated by Ajax.

I wouldn't remove the whole line though but keep this:

```php
/**
 * @var string
 * @Validate("Haffner\JhCaptcha\Validation\Validator\ReCaptchaValidator") 
 */
protected $captchaResponse;
```

Looking in the [code](https://github.com/TehTux/jh_captcha/blob/develop/Classes/Validation/Validator/ReCaptchaValidator.php), this is the essential part:

```php
$apiResponse = json_decode(
    GeneralUtility::getUrl($url.'?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$value),
    true
);
```

The link goes to the google api and they analyze the transferred value to return an error code. Based on the google-error-code the extension code adds a distinct message to the error if the verification failed.

So I'd consider the captcha as safe and doubt that it will pass without input.

EDIT:
Above your model class you've to note this:

```php
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Annotation\Validate;
```

Additionally there will be a [new feature in TYPO3 v12](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/12.0/Feature-96688-AttributesForExtbaseAnnotations.html), it will support [native PHP annotations](https://stitcher.io/blog/attributes-in-php-8) that exist since PHP v8.
Actually I'm not quite sure if or how far support from TYPO3 itself is even required for this feature but the different [validator class-files](https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/tree/main/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Annotation) include code that is related to it.
So for TYPO3 v12 the validation annotation would look like this:

```
#[Validate(['validator' => '\Haffner\JhCaptcha\Validation\Validator\ReCaptchaValidator'])]
```

Comment: But keeping the valide-lin gives this error: [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Validate" in property $captchaResponse was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?

Comment: I did edit my answer and commented here already about it, somehow the comment is gone. Anyway, have a look again ;-)

Comment: Yes, now the page trows an error if the ReCaptcha is empty. I though get this error: An error occurred while trying to call ... Controller->createAction(). Any ideas how to debug that error?

Comment: Likely you get this error: `$this->addError('missingInputResponse', 1426877525);` shown in the log file. Question is how to  catch it and display something useful for the user instead.

Comment: The best is to suppress sending by javascript if the value is empty or of the wrong string-length. Then the server is not bothered with it, nevertheless a nice handling would be good there too,